# Singleton Class variables returns nil outside initialization function

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I am learning Swift with XCode 8 and have been developing this simple weather app. The app pulls data from openweather.org public APIs for the current weather and next 10 days weather forecast.

Everything is working fine in terms of pulling the data from the openweather API in JSON format with static latitude and longitude, and displaying them in the UI (which consists of a UIView for current weather and a UITableView for the Forecast data of 10 days). The app looks like
this-

[image]

Now, I am implementing `CoreLocation` protocol to use the devices GPS to get the latitude and longitude (instead of hard coded coordinates) and then store the lat/long into a singleton class variables. The singleton class looks like below-

```
import CoreLocation

class Location{
    static var sharedInstance = Location()
    private init(){}
    var latitude: Double!
    var longitude: Double!        
}
```

Now in my Main ViewController, I have a function which initializes the `LocationManager` to fetch the devices location (lat/long) and then store it into the singleton class variables `latitude` and `longitude`. The function is called from the `ViewdidAppear`. The Main view Controller looks like this-

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class WeatherVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
....
....
//IBOutlets etc.
//Some vars etc.
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
        
        ......//a few more lines of code here
       
        
   print(Location.sharedInstance.latitude,Location.sharedInstance.longitude)// this prints nil, nil
        
    }

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        locationAuthStatus()
    }

func locationAuthStatus(){
        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse{
            currentLocation = locationManager.location
            Location.sharedInstance.latitude = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude
            Location.sharedInstance.longitude = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude
            print(Location.sharedInstance.latitude,Location.sharedInstance.longitude) //this prints the correct values
        }else{
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            locationAuthStatus() 
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have a constants file which holds certain global Constants for the app such as the openweather API URL etc. It is here where I would like to use the singleton class variables `Location.sharedInstance.latitude` and `Location.sharedInstance.longitude`. The constants file has a variable that constructs 2 API URLS like so-

```
let CURRENT_WEATHER_URL = "\(BASE_URL)\(LATITUDE)\(Location.sharedInstance.latitude)\(LONGITUDE)\(Location.sharedInstance.longitude)\(APP_ID)\(API_KEY)"

let FORECAST_WEATHER_URL = "\(FORECAST_URL)\(LATITUDE)\(Location.sharedInstance.latitude)\(LONGITUDE)\(Location.sharedInstance.longitude)\(FORECAST_CNT)\(APP_ID)\(API_KEY)"
```

However, `Location.sharedInstance.latitude` and `Location.sharedInstance.longitude` is always returning `nil` outside of the `locationAuthStatus()` function so the lat/long values in `CURRENT_WEATHER_URL` and `FORECAST_WEATHER_URL` shows up as `nil` as a result of which the API call fails . There is a print statement inside `locationAuthStatus()` function which prints the `Location.sharedInstance.latitude` and `Location.sharedInstance.longitude` values correctly but somehow these values refuse to propagate to the rest of the application (in other classes). I have tried printing these from all of the other classes I have in the project and all of them return `nil`.

I am still learning more about Singleton classes and Swift in general, but some insight on what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `viewDidLoad` executes before `viewDidAppear`, so if you call `locationAuthStatus()` (where you set lat/long) from `viewDidAppear`, they haven't yet been set in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Wow! I was under the impression that the execution sequence was vice versa. Thanks let me try.

Comment: You can't simply access locationManager.location like this. It is async. You need to add the method `func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {` and get the `locations` property there

Comment: you need also to call `locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()` or `requestLocation()` for a single location. Don't forget to implement also `locationManager(_:didFailWithError:)`

Comment: @LeoDabus thank you. For now, simply calling `locationAuthStatus()` from `viewDidLoad` as suggested by @Samantha worked for me (I just tried), but now I am curious about the function you mentioned since, I am suspecting that my current code may not work on the phone very well (currently using simulator only).

Comment: or may not work at all

Comment: Ooops! Sorry, I was way ahead of myself. It didn't work in the simulator :( (As you suspected). Calling `locationAuthStatus()` in the `viewDidLoad` isn't working. I am going to give your suggestions a try. Just curious, I am following a tutorial where the instructor does it exactly the way I did and somehow it works for him. the video is in XCode Beta 8.

Comment: @LeoDabus so I did some reading on `didUpdateLocations` delegate method. I am using `locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` in my code, so in this case is the delegate really required because I would use  `startUpdatingLocation()` which is probably not required since the Location Services won't be in use when the app is not being used anyways (i'd probably have to `stopUpdatingLocation()` as well). So is it more of a best practice? I tried the app with "Freeway Drive" mode and so far it seems to be working without the delegates.

Comment: As I said for a single location you can use `requestLocation()` you need also to get the single location inside the method `locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:)` or handle the error in the method `locationManager(_:didFailWithError:)`

Comment: Gotcha! so `startUpdatingLocation()` if I also have `requestAlwaysAuthorization` and  `requestLocation()` for only `requestWhenInUseAuthorization`. This makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620548-requestlocation

Comment: Yep, I just read that and implemented it, and it's working perfectly. I was also (theoretically) able to prevent a crash with `didFailWithError` (by defaulting it with a hard coded coordinates) that was happening in "Freeway Drive" mode when sometimes ios couldn't get coordinates.